# SpecFlow not finding packages even when installed through NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2013, specflow

I've installed SpecFlow using the NuGet console, and it says it's installed correctly:

```
Install-Package SpecFlow.NUnit
Attempting to resolve dependency 'SpecFlow'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NUnit (≥ 2.6)'.
'SpecFlow.NUnit 1.1.1' already installed.

Install-Package SpecFlow
'SpecFlow 1.9.0' already installed.
```

But when I try to build I get errors:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TechTalk' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Also, I don't get the context menu for creating the step definitions. SpecFlow feature is available as a project type, though, and syntax highlighting works fine for the gherkin file.

So what am I missing?

Comment: have you also installed the [visual studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/90ac3587-7466-4155-b591-2cd4cc4401bc)?

Comment: Yes, that's installed, and showing under Tools | Extensions and Updates.

Comment: your output says that the package is already installed, not that it installed correctly. looks like something is corrupted to me. I'd remove, delete all the packages folders and reinstall.

Comment: Are you using the right versions of the packages? And are the references to the packages from your solution correct?

Answer (score 0):

So I know this question is old, but I came across it while trying to fix a similar problem today. Just in case anyone else comes across this problem, here's my solution, hope it helps.

I had six projects which I tried to add SpecFlow 2.1 to using nuget. Two were successful, four did not show the dll in references and gave errors about (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). After some digging around I noticed that the two projects that were successful were targeting .NET 4.5 in their project properties and the four that weren't were targeting .NET 4.0. I changed them all to target 4.5.2 and hey-presto, adding specflow through nuget worked fine.

If anyone gets a similar problem, checking your project properties might be worth a try.

[image]